# How to get string of JSON settings in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm new to python and still I love it but this makes me really frustrated.

I'm trying to load 4 settings in my console app since `Write.Input` causing errors when converting .exe file, so I was thinking instead let user type and hit enter it would be wise to load some `.JSON settings` file.
I need to get all values from `"amount"; "threads"` etc...

My Json settings file **settings.json**

```
{ "settings_data":[
    {
        "amount": 1000,
        "threads": 5,
        "type": 1,
        "id": "sK19"
    }
]}
```

My Code:

```
with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "settings.json"), "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    settings = json.loads(f.read())

sendTypeA = json.dumps(settings)
sendTypeB = json.loads(sendTypeA)
sendType = sendTypeB["type"]
```

ERROR:

```
    Exception has occurred: KeyError
'type'
File "D:\pyprograms\main\main.py", line 38, in <module>
    sendType = sendTypeB["type"]
```

Comment: That dictionary does not have a top-level key named "type".  The only top-level key is "settings_data".  I think you want `sendTypeB["settings_data"][0]["type"]`

Comment: Also, `settings` is already the loaded json object.  Why are you using two more variables to dump it to a string and then re-load it from json?

Comment: You can also just pass `f` directly to `json.dump`, which is a wrapper around `json.dumps` that calls the `read` method for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "settings.json"), "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    settings = json.loads(f.read())

sendType = settings["settings_data"][0]["type"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
sendType = sendTypeB["type"]
```

...you need...

```
sendType = sendTypeB["settings_data"][0]["type"]
```

...because the "type" key is in a dictionary that's in the first element of the list referred to by sendTypeB["settings_data"]